# python programming help for equation

Tags: python, ipython

I am new to python and trying to learn some codes. This is my first programming attempt with python. I have a sequence S and a sequence T(which is also a relation of a couples recurrence relationship equation)where

Sn= 2S(n-1)+S(n-2)+4T(n-1)

and T=S(n-1)+T(n-1).

S0=1, S1=2, T0=0 AND T1=1.

How can i write a function that returns nth value of S and T sequence where the function takes n as a parameter and returns Sn,Tn as a tuple as result of calling the function?

Comment: Check [recursive functions](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php)

Comment: And then replace it with an iterative function when you realize it's too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the recursive functions:

```
def T(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return S(n - 1) + T(n - 1)

def S(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    return 2 * S(n - 1) + S(n - 2) + 4 * T(n - 1)

def tuple_func(n):
    return(S(n), T(n))
```

Somewhere between `n == 20` and `n == 30` this becomes ridiculously slow, depending on your threshold for ridiculousness.

"For fun" I've converted the recursive functions to an iterative version. On my computer it can do up to `n == 50,000` in about a second.

```
def tuple_func(n):
    S = [1, 2]
    T = [0, 1]
    if n < 0:
        return(None, None)
    if 0 >= n < 2:
        return(S[n], T[n])
    for n in range(2, n + 1):
        S.append(2 * S[n - 1] + S[n - 2] + 4 * T[n - 1])
        T.append(S[n - 1] + T[n - 1])
    return(S[n], T[n])
```